# What is the cleanest way of the following (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, function, optimization

I have a huge cities table containing around 3,000,000 rows. I needed to create a new column which contains the following line:

```
'City name, City name with accent, Country name'
```

Basic Schema is as follows:

```
city_id         int 
name            varchar
status          varchar
date_created    int(11)
country_id      int
accent_name     varchar
city_country    text
```

And there is the countries table which contains the contry_id and its name.

Now I figured out 2 ways to fill the city_country column.

**Attempt 1:**

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION getConcat(x INT(11))
    RETURNS TEXT
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE var1 TEXT;
    SELECT concat(CT.name, ', ', CT.accent_name, ', ', CR.name) AS Combined INTO var1 FROM `wp_City` AS CT LEFT JOIN `wp_Country` AS CR ON CR.country_id = CT.country_id WHERE CT.city_id = x;
    RETURN var1;
END//
UPDATE `wp_City` SET `city_country`=(SELECT getConcat(city_id)) WHERE 1;
```

**Attempt 2:**

I created a new table containing just one column:

```
INSERT INTO `_myCity` (name, status, date_created, country_id, accent_name, lat, `long`, region, city_country)
    SELECT c.name, c.status, c.date_created, c.country_id, c.accent_name, c.lat, c.long, c.region, _c.name
    FROM `wp_City` as c inner join `wp_Country` _c on c.country_id = _c.country_id
```

Now the second way is much faster, but which is cleaner? The above will be executed only once, so the question is simply out of curiosity. If there are better ways of achieving this please do share!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any reason you're denormalizing the data like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to do something like this I would rather go with a view that adds the column when needed (thus avoiding the additional overhead imposed by storing redundant data in the table on disk)